# Cannot get user selected phone number using ABPeoplePickerNavigationController

Tags: ios

The use case is quite simple. The app will pop up iPhone's contacts list and want to get the selected phone number. `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController` is used. The problem is when a contact has multiple phone numbers, no matter which phone number the user selects in Contact details page, it's always the last phone number returned.

The code is actually simple and common.

```
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person property:    (ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier
{    
    NSString *selectedNumber = nil;
    if (property == kABPersonPhoneProperty)
    {
        ABMultiValueRef numbers = ABRecordCopyValue(person, property);
        selectedNumber = (__bridge NSString *) ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(numbers, ABMultiValueGetIndexForIdentifier(numbers, identifier));
    }
}
```

`identifier` should be identifier of selected phone number. But no matter what the user selects, the value of `identifier` is always `0`.

I also tried another way,

```
ABMultiValueRef multiPhones = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
NSInteger number = ABMultiValueGetCount(multiPhones);
```

But value of `number` in above code is always `1`. Only one phone number can be retrieved using this API.

I checked iPhone's default Messages application, it has the same behaviour. If a user has multiple phone numbers, the last one is always used. So I think this may be a limitation of iOS. But when using Messages application, if I start typing contact's number, in the suggested drop-down list, the contact's all phone numbers are actually listed, which makes me very confused.

When I tested using iPhone simulator, it works fine. But once deployed to real iPhone 4S with iOS 7, it doesn't work. The only difference is iPhone simulator version is 7.0.3, but my iPhone is using 7.0.4.

I do need some guidance about this issue. Is this feature actually feasible?

Comment: Strange. I have the same code in an app and I can properly pick any phone number from any user in my Contacts and get the expected result.

Comment: The strange thing is that Messages application has the same behaviour. And I cannot use the API to retrieve a contact's all phone numbers.

Comment: This seems to indicate there is a problem with your contacts database.